# Adding a custom search param to the sails.js api

Tags: sails.js

I need to find all models in a radius, my models have `lat,lng` attributes,
im using postgres with `cube` and `earthdistance` extensions,

I created a `new route` that returns the models inside the radius, but this routes lost all the base functionality that sails provides in its index search route.

```
  .query("SELECT * FROM cheer WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth($1, $2), $3) @> ll_to_earth(model.lat, model.lng); ", [lat, long, radInMet], function (err, raw) {
    let models = raw.rows || [];

    res.send(models);
  });
```

for example: if i want to populate associated models i can't add it as a query param, like i would normally do.

How would i add this search query without losing the blueprint api's base functionality?
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-where

Comment: Could you show more code ? what do you mean by :  if i want to populate associated models i can't add it as a query param, like i would normally do ?

Comment: @HamzaFatmi what i ment is the if i would want to make a request to my api to fetch models with an association i would use `GET /model?populate=association` but i created a custom route so that doesn't work any more , in my case `GET /model/radius`

Comment: @HamzaFatmi what i am trying to do is to be able to use the default blueprint api's index route with all the search functionality and add a custom search param of my own (in this case search by radius)

Comment: since you have a custom route, you can't use the blueprint  functionalities anymore, but you still can do anything the blueprint does, you can populate your associations in the route handler.

Comment: @HamzaFatmi i know i can do that, Im trying not to do that, because then i would have to implement all of the functions again, what im trying to do is add a search param, i don't mind overriding the basic index function, what is the correct way according to sails to do this?

Comment: @HamzaFatmi notice how this laravel library solved this issue https://github.com/selahattinunlu/laravel-api-query-builder/wiki/Creating-Custom-Filter

Comment: If I got correctly what you are trying to do, then you can try to require the  `find.js` from sails hooks and use it inside your route handler , so you don't have to override the basic functionalities https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/04c0c9133f01bfb79af9b3a609f986abe121945e/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/find.js.